# Close question because lack of information?

Tags: discussion

I am pretty big on broadening the scope of questions for the site but I feel a lot of questions "sit" because lack of information.  This is usually because the OP doesn't respond to questions or doesn't return after posting.

Maybe give them a month and delete if question doesn't have enough information to properly answer?

Answer (score 3):

Unanswered (in the Stack Exchange sense of having no or no upvoted answers) are already automatically deleted if they meet certain criteria. These are detailed in [this Meta Stack Overflow answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

The basic rules are that:

- Negatively scoring questions with no answer are deleted after 30 days.
- Low (0 or 1) scoring questions with no owner are deleted after a year.
- Closed (not duplicate) questions with no answers and a score of 0 or less are deleted after 9 days.

So if the question fits these criteria it will be automatically deleted and there's nothing to do.

Comment: Or the thing to do is to down vote the bad questions so that they meet the criteria. Though with the new "on hold" status, I think it's also helpful to vote to close so that no one tries to answer a question without enough details. We can always remove a downvote and reopen questions after they are edited.

Comment: There are a lot of examples that have positive votes - http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28036/how-can-i-repair-these-cracks-in-my-balcony-wall.  I just think it would help if there was some sort of clock the OP could see that said your question can't be answered without more input and here is how much time you have or you need to ask it again.  I guess this would go for all stackexchange sites but I really see it here.

Comment: There's a 5 day clock that goes with the new "on hold" status before it automatically closes the question. That gives feedback to the user that they need to fix it, or their question will go away. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons